# How to run method on startup and schedule according the the cron expression and avoid parallel execution

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, startup, spring-scheduled

I want to run job every day at 14:00. Also  I want to run that job after application startup. This job is long enough(lets say 10 min) and I am afraid what happens if startup happens at 13:58. I want to forbid concurrent task execution.

Will the below work?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 14 * * *")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
  jobMehod();        
}
public synchronized void jobMehod(){
  // code wihout creation new threads
}
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void onStartup(){
    jobMehod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a `synchronized` method if using the default spring scheduler.

It is single threaded so will not run more than one scheduled task at a time.